# Problem in C : How to properly call function inside main

Tags: c, data-structures

So there is this project in Data Structures that i have to deal with this semester and it requires that i have to code in C . The problem is that i am a little bit rusty in C and i am dealing with basic problems. One of the problems is that i have to write a simple program in C that implements BubbleSort . The BubbleSort algorithm has to be a seperate function and call it in the main program . Here is my effort . The problem is that it doesnt type the sorted array . I hope you can help me .

THE CODE :

```
int calculateRand()
{
    int num;
    num = (rand())%(UPPER-LOWER+1)+LOWER;
    return num;
}

void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    int temp=*xp;
    *xp=*yp;
    *yp=temp;
}

void BubbleSort(int S[], int n)
{
    int up=n;
    int i,j;

    while(up>1)
    {
        j=0;
        for(i=1; i<up-1; i++)
        {
            if(S[i]>S[i+1])
            {
                swap(&S[i], &S[i+1]);
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", S[i]);
    }

}


int main()
{
    int n,i;
    printf("Parakalw dwste mia timh sto n: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int S[sizeof(n)];


    printf("O mi taxinomimenos pinakas einai o exis \n");
    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        S[i]=calculateRand();
        printf("%d\n", S[i]);
    }

    printf("O pinakas meta thn taxinomisi einai \n");
    BubbleSort(S[sizeof(n)], n);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may be unaware of this, but `sizeof(n)` will return the number of bytes an `int` takes up on your system, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Did you mean `int S[n];` and `BubbleSort(S, n);`? The call `BubbleSort(S[sizeof(n)], n);` probably passes the value of the 5th element and this should give a compiler error.

Comment: `while(up>1)` looks like an infinite loop.  i don't see `up` changing.  also, what is `j` doing?

Comment: The way you call BubbleSort in main is wrong for the first argument. Expected `int*` but you pass `int`. Just use the name of array `S`, which is a pointer to the first element of array

Comment: are you compiling with warnings enabled?

Comment: Welp all your answers helped me find the solution ! Thanks for the quick response ! I will later post the fully correct code :)

Comment: Please don't do that: leave the question as it is.

Comment: you can post the correct code as an answer to this question

Comment: Ok sure , but why ?

Comment: Because the question section is for questions, and the answer section is for solutions.

Comment: If you edit the question with the correct code, the previous comments and previous answers (there are none now, but someone might write one) will no longer make sense in context

Comment: i would add the answer as a comment :)

Answer (score 2):

So if we start from the top there is a problem in the `calculateRand()` function as you do not declare the `UPPER` and `LOWER` variables or pass them as parameters to function.
Swap function is ok.
In the `BubbleSort()` function you need to decrease the `up` variable value after the for loop.

```
while(up>1)
{
    for(i=1; i<up-1; i++)
    {
        if(S[i]>S[i+1])
        {
            swap(&S[i], &S[i+1]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    up--;
}
```

Also at this point you should start iterating from 0 instead of 1 since arrays start from index 0. So `for(i=0; i<up-1; i++)` is the correct way to go.

Lastly in the `main()` function when you're declaring the array variable `S` you shouldn't pass the `sizeof(n)` since `n` is an integer and size of an integer is 4. Instead you want to use `n` as it is `int S[n];`

For loop to populate the array should go up to `n` not `n-1` if you want to fill all elements of the array. However if you change this you'll need to make the similar change in the `BubbleSort()` function.

And finally in the `BubbleSort()` function call you are passing the last element of the array which is an integer whereas function expects you to pass an array. It should look like this `BubbleSort(S, n);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. sizeof(n) has nothing to do with the value of the variable n. It's the the size of the variable n, i.e. mostly 4 bytes for the modern architectures.
2. Modern variants of C permit variable size arrays thus

   `int S[n];`
   would have been legit. Otherwise

   `int *S = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));`

   will help.
3. When you call BubbleSort , your argument should be S not S[sizeof(n)];